# How many ways are there to win Settlers of Catan?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

The object of the board game "The Settlers of Catan" is to obtain 10 "victory points". There are five ways to obtain victory points:

1. Settlements, worth 1 victory point. Each player starts the game with 2 settlements and can build up to 3 more, for a total of 5.
2. Cities, worth 2 victory points. Cities are built on top of settlements, replacing them in doing so. Players can build up to 4 cities.
3. Victory Point development cards, worth 1 victory point. Players can buy up to 5 such cards from the deck.
4. The Longest Road card, either held or not held, worth 2 victory points.
5. The Largest Army card, either held or not held, worth 2 victory points.

I remember that we can decompose this into the number of integer solutions to the equation:

$$
s + 2c + v + 2r + 2a = 10
$$
where
$$
0\leq s \leq 5; 0 \leq c \leq 4; 0 \leq v \leq 5; 0 \leq r \leq 1; 0 \leq a \leq 1
$$

and

$$
s + c \geq 2
$$

to account for the 2 starting settlements that can be upgraded into cities.

Also, it is possible to have 9 victory points and then take Longest Road or Largest Army, bringing your total to 11. I think the number of additional solutions here is

$$
\text{Solutions}(s + 2c + v = 9) + 2\times\text{Solutions}(s + 2c + v = 7)
$$

multiplying by 2 to account for interchangeability of Longest Road and Largest Army, with bounds as above.

However, I don't remember how to find the number of solutions to these equations.

---

At commenters' request, here are some example solutions:

- 2 settlements, 2 cities, Longest Road, and Largest Army; $2 + 2(2) + 2 + 2 = 10$
- 4 settlements, 1 city, 4 Victory Point cards: 4 + 2(1) + 4 = 10
- Player has 4 cities and 1 Victory Point card and takes Longest Road, 2(4) + 1 + 2 = 11
- Player has 3 settlements, 1 city, 2 Victory Point cards, and Longest Road and takes Largest Army, 3 + 2(1) + 2 + 2 + 2 = 11

Comment: It might help if you gave an example or two of a "path to victory" so that we can see more clearly what it is you are trying to count. In particular, does the *order* in which you acquire victory points matter? (Also, I think the formula you want is $s+2c+v+2r+2a=10$, since the Longest Road and Largest Army cards are, like Cities, worth $2$ points each.)

Comment: Another question: Is it not possible to have $9$ victory points and then build another City, bringing your total to $11$? (You don't mention it as possible.)

Comment: @BarryCipra Added, and the order does not matter. That is not possible. Cities must be built on top of an existing settlement, so they can only increase the Victory Point total by 1 when they are built. Good question, though.

Comment: @BarryCipra Fixed.

Comment: I just noticed one more potential problem: The constraints as given allow for $(s,c,v,r,a)=(2,4,0,0,0)$ as a solution. But is it possible to build $4$ cities yet leave $2$ settlements? Do you want the extra constraint to be $2\le s+c\le5$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, that is possible. You could build 4 settlements, upgrade them all to cities, then build 2 more.

Comment: Oooh I love Catan.  Great question!  BTW I don't recommend adding the following complication, but it is theoretically possible to score $12$ pts under this exact scenario (which I have never seen in the $200+$ games I've played):  You have $9$ points and $<5$ settlements and someone else holds the Longest Road.  You build an extra settlement, breaking up that player's road, resulting in your existing road being longest.  Thus you gained $3$ points with that one build and jumped from $9$ to $12$ instantaneously (atomically).  Like I said, though, lets not add this super-rare case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting slightly, you have 
$$s + v + 2(c + r + a) = 10$$ subject to $$0\leq s \leq 5 \\ 0 \leq v \leq 5 \\ 0 \leq c \leq 4 \\ 0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ 0 \leq a \leq 1 \\ s + c \ge 2$$
So clearly $s$ and $v$ must have the same parity. I think the easiest way to count solutions is to case split on $c+r+a$ ignoring the final constraint:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
c+r+a & \textrm{Number of solutions} & s+v & \textrm{Number of solutions} & \textrm{Total}  \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 10 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 3 & 8 & 3 & 9 \\
\hline
2 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 20 \\
\hline
3 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 20 \\
\hline
4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 12 \\
\hline
5 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
& & & \textrm{Grand total} & 65 &
\end{array}$$

and then subtract the cases $s+c < 2$. If $s=c=0$ then the others can only total 9, so there are two cases:

1. $s=0, c=1$: $s+v \le 5$ and $c+r+a \le 3$ so the only case is $s=0, v=4, c=1, r=1, a=1$;
2. $s=1, c=0$: $s+v \le 6$ and $c+r+a \le 2$ so the only case is $s=1, v=5, c=0, r=1, a=1$.

Therefore we have 63 solutions.

---

I disagree with you on the second case. I think that the correct way to state it is

$$s + v + 2(c + r + a) = 11$$ subject to $$0\leq s \leq 5 \\ 0 \leq v \leq 5 \\ 0 \leq c \leq 4 \\ 0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ 0 \leq a \leq 1 \\ r + a \ge 1$$

Then the same case split gives

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
c+r+a & \textrm{Number of solutions} & s+v & \textrm{Number of solutions} & \textrm{Total}  \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 9 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 12 \\
\hline
3 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 18 \\
\hline
4 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 12 \\
\hline
5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\
\hline
& & & \textrm{Grand total} & 52 &
\end{array}$$

Here we only have one overcount case:

- If $s=0, c=1$ then we get $s=0, v=5, c=1, r=1, a=1$.
- If $s=1, c=0$ then we can't get a total of 11.

So we get 51 solutions, which added to the previous 63 makes 114.

Comment: +1 nice modeling of the $11$ points case via $r+a \ge 1$

Comment: Although [WolframAlpha gives the same answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+2b+%2B+c+%2B+2d+%2B+2e+%3D+10;+0+%3C%3D+a+%3C%3D+5;+0+%3C%3D+b+%3C%3D+4;+0+%3C%3D+c+%3C%3D+5;+0+%3C%3D+d+%3C%3D+1;+0+%3C%3D+e+%3C%3D+1;+a+%2B+b+%3E%3D+2), I'm not sure it's correct. Consider the case $(s, v, c, r, a) = (1, 5, 0, 1, 1)$. It is illegal because $s + c < 2$, but I think it is counted in table 1 row 3 (the row starting with $c + r + a = 2$).

Comment: I overlooked the constraint $s+c\ge 2$. My bad. I'll edit shortly.

Comment: Should the "total" in table 1 row 5 not be 3? I count 3 possible solutions to $c + r + a = 5: (c, r, a) = (3, 1, 1), (4, 1, 0), (4, 0, 1)$.

Comment: @StackExchange, also correct. Not my finest hour. Still, it explains why Wolfram Alpha gave the same answer: my errors cancelled each other out.

Comment: @antkam notes that it is possible to have 9 VPs then build a settlement that breaks someone else's Longest Road and passes Longest Road to you, winning with 12 VPs. We can model this as $s + v + 2c + 2a = 9$, subject to the constraints as in the 10 case except that $s \leq 4$. [WolframAlpha says there are 28 more solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%2B+2b+%2B+c+%2B+2d+%3D+9%3B+0+%3C%3D+a+%3C%3D+4%3B+0+%3C%3D+b+%3C%3D+4%3B+0+%3C%3D+c+%3C%3D+5%3B+0+%3C%3D+d+%3C%3D+1%3B+a+%2B+b+%3E%3D+2), bringing the final total to 142.